# CSS Focus Dropdown menu disappears when clicking child li

Tags: css, menu, focus, submenu

I am having problems with my drop down menu. When I try to click on one of the links in the sub-menu, focus is lost from the parent and so the menu disappears, making it impossible to follow the links in the sub-menu. I have searched this forum and google and although there are many similar issues, I can't find any solutions to my particular problem. I would greatly appreciate any help on this. The site is [www.emmatuscaloosa.com](http://www.emmatuscaloosa.com) and the sub-menu is under the "categories" button.

Comment: do you have a javascript function on click event?

Comment: I don't...  I would like to keep it purely CSS,  I'm sure it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a pretty simple fix for this by adding some CSS to the sub menu hover state. Im hiding / showing the sub menu using the max-height property and fixed the issue by writing:

```
.sub-menu:hover {
   max-height:100%
}
```

That simple! Whenever the mouse is hovering on any sub menu item the menu must stay visible, allowing enough time to click on the enclosed links.  Not sure if this is the "proper" way to fix the issue but it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Dont display the sub-menu none.. rather hide it with opacity.

Answer (score -1):

Dont' use focus. There are other ways, for example you could use :target or :hover to open the submenu. Using target, you will have to add an id to the submenu. 
Target:

```
.sub-menu{display:none;}
#categories:target{display:block}
```

Another way is to use Javascript.

Comment: I have tried hover also but the same problem arises.  As soon as the mouse leaves the parent item the menu disappears...

Comment: What do you think about the target solution?